# Run two blazor WASM apps inside a single WASM-hosted project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I am using the latest preview for a WebAssembly (WASM) hosted Blazor app. I have set up a WASM hosted app and configured it to use a base `href` of `/App1/` inside of the `wwwroot/index.html` file of the client app folder:

```
<base href="/App1/" />
```

At this point, my app structure is like so:

1. Client
2. Server
3. Shared

I then mapped the app in the server app folder to the route:

```cs
app.Map("/app1", app1 =>
{
    app1.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app1.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app1.UseStaticFiles();
    app1.UsePathBase("/app1");
    app1.UseRouting();

    app1.UseIdentityServer();
    app1.UseAuthentication();
    app1.UseAuthorization();
    app1.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });
});
```

Running this with a couple of launch setting changes to map to `/app1` works fantastic. Next, I copied the client app and changed the namespace and `csproj` to `App2`.

My app structure would now be:

1. App1 (Client app)
2. App2 (Client app)
3. Server
4. Shared

I set the base `href` to `/App2/`, and I added a second mapping to the server startup:

```cs
app.Map("/app1", app1 =>
{
    app1.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app1.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app1.UseStaticFiles();
    app1.UsePathBase("/app1");
    app1.UseRouting();

    app1.UseIdentityServer();
    app1.UseAuthentication();
    app1.UseAuthorization();
    app1.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });
});

app.Map("/app2", app2 =>
{
    app2.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app2.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app2.UseStaticFiles();
    app2.UsePathBase("/app2");
    app2.UseRouting();

    app2.UseIdentityServer();
    app2.UseAuthentication();
    app2.UseAuthorization();
    app2.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });
});
```

However, the project doesn't run. It complains that the static files are still merged together. I get this compile error when trying to run the server project with `dotnet run`:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(191,5): error : Conflicting assets with the same path '/appsettings.Development.json' for content root paths '/Users/user/Developer/WasmHosted/App1/wwwroot/appsettings.Development.json' and '/Users/user/Developer/WasmHosted/App2/wwwroot/appsettings.Development.json'.
```

I've also tried adding a `commandLineArgs` to change the content root location in the `launchsettings` of the client apps with no effect:

```
"commandLineArgs": "--contentroot=/app1",
```

Any suggestions would be incredibly appreciated, as I don't know what else to try.

This is the `dotnet new` command I used to create the project

```
dotnet new blazorwasm -au Individual -ho -n WasmHosted
```

Comment: Answer probably lies in using `<StaticWebAssetBasePath>`. This issue might prove helpful https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20580

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javier, a team member of the Blazor project, has developed an example project here:
https://github.com/javiercn/BlazorMultipleApps/blob/master/BlazorMultipleApps

Answer (score 1):

You can ref to [**app.UseMulitSpa**](https://github.com/DukeCheng/OpenBlog/blob/master/OpenBlog.Web/Startup.cs#L204), I have Created a new Library [**WasmService**](https://github.com/DukeCheng/OpenBlog/tree/master/OpenBlog.BlazorWasmService) for handle this

Use Steps:
[**step 1**](https://github.com/DukeCheng/OpenBlog/tree/master/OpenBlog.BlazorWasmService): Set the blazor wasm app root place folder under wwwroot
[**step 2**](https://github.com/DukeCheng/OpenBlog/blob/master/OpenBlog.Web/Startup.cs#L204): use app.UseMulitSpa to add blazor wasm app, you need define a public path,

During the run, Main host app will use standalone port for every blazor wasm app, and [**WasmService**](https://github.com/DukeCheng/OpenBlog/tree/master/OpenBlog.BlazorWasmService) have a internal proxy for main host app call.

Comment: The link to `app.UseMultiSpa` is broken. Plz advise.